# Error Installing Big Sur - Macbook Fails to Boot to OS

Tags: install, big-sur

I have a MacBook Pro (2018 I think?) and tried upgrading to Big Sur through the OS's "app updates". It successfully downloaded the files, restarted the computer and began the install. The install was stuck with the progress bar about 1/3 full and "less than a minute remaining" for over 3 hours.

I read that some people overcame this by turning their computer off and on manually, so I gave that a shot. The install kept failing with "An error occurred while applying the selected software update", so I rebooted in recovery mode and selected to reinstall Big Sur, which supposedly causes a fresh download and install.

Now it usually gets to about 2/3 full and "12 minutes remaining" then fails either with "an error occurred loading the update" or just restarts directly into recovery mode. I tried using the disk utility to repair the hard drive but it found no errors. At this point, there is no other operating system to boot into (nothing shows up in startup disks) and I unfortunately have no time machine backups.

Does anyone have any idea how I can unbrick my laptop?